# Animate color change of shape for certain number of frames EaselJs

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, easeljs

I am using EaselJS and want to create a flashing color rectangle that will flash a certain number of times when a button is pressed, displaying random colors from an array. It should stop after 10 color flashes and then I want to extract the final color.

So far the relevant code I have is:

```
var colorArray = ["#FE7B62","#CB2DD3","#F1FD66","#004CE8","#FFD068", "#02A97E"];
square = new createjs.Shape();
square.graphics.beginFill("#000").drawRoundRect(850, 50, 100, 100, 20);

function pushButton(event) {
    square.graphics.inject(animateColor);
}

function animateColor(event) {
    this.fillStyle = colorArray[parseInt(Math.random()*6)];
}
```

This code successfully triggers the flashing of colors from my color array, but I am not sure what the best method of running the animation for a limited number of frames is. I tried pausing the ticker and restarting it on the onclick of the button but that failed. I also tried using a for loop in the pushButton function but that caused a "too much recursion error" in the browser. Here is my full file link https://github.com/RMehta95/sherman-land/blob/master/main.js.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an event to trigger your action (xamountOfFrames).  Here is a link to some information that might help

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: EaselJS has a built in eventlistener that can trigger a function on click, which is what I'm using. My main issue is limiting the number of color flashes instead of having it continually iterate.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using the inject function and instead redrawing the shape each time, creating a couple counter and timer variables to ensure that it looped through the proper amount of times.

```
function pushButton() {
    if (timer === false) {
        animate = setInterval(animateColor, 200);
        timer = true;
    }
}

function animateColor() {
    square.graphics.clear();
    displayColor = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length)];
    square.graphics.beginFill(displayColor).drawRoundRect(850, 50, 100, 100, 20);
    counter++;
    if (counter===15) {
        clearInterval(animate);
        counter=0;
        movePlayer(displayColor);
        timer = false;
        return;
    }
}
```